# How to renew M365 groups when they get close to expiration?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

Here is my current powershell script. My current issue is that script will say that the group is close to expiration regardless. Been having trouble on how to find an easy way to get the date.

```
# Define the list of group IDs
$group_ids = @(
    "GID1"
    "GID2"
    "GID3"
)

# Set the number of days before expiration to consider a group as close to expiring
$daysBeforeExpiration = 30


# Filter groups that are close to expiring
 foreach ($groupId in $group_ids) {
    $group = Get-MgGroup -GroupId $groupId
    $expirationDateTime = [datetime]::Parse($group.resourceProvisioningOptions[0].value)
        if ($expirationDateTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays($daysBeforeExpiration)) {
             Write-Host "Group $($group.displayName) is close to expiration...."

            # Renew the group

            # Invoke-MgRenewGroup -GroupId $groupId

            # Write-Host "Group $($group.displayName) renewed successfully."
        } else {
            Write-Host "Group $($group.displayName) is not close to expiration."
        }
    }
```

I want to get compare the expiration date to if it is 30 days within expiration.

Comment: I think you need [Update-MgGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.groups/update-mggroup?view=graph-powershell-1.0#-expirationdatetime) and use the `ExpirationDateTime` parameter for that